# Designing in the browser with a grid but without Photoshop?

Tags: grid, susy

I'm planning on designing my next website purely in the browser, but would like to use a grid system. I'm pretty new to grid systems, and when I've looked into them they all recommend I use Photoshop to layer the grid image over my design. If I want to use a grid system but not Photoshop, do I just use something like [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) to view the grid in the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a web grid system recommend using photoshop, so I'm not sure where you saw that - but you certainly can use Susy to view (and manage) your grid directly in the browser.